# running ib_insyn in a while true loop that buys and sells on TWS instance

Tags: python, tws, ib-insync

I run the code below, but it seams to get out of sync with TWS. The first order will work, but then the positions call will not return what shows up in TWS. I think it has something to do with started to listening to the port then sending orders and losing the next valid ID for incoming messages from TWS. How would I write the below in asynchronous format? I know I can wrap things in tasks then run them in the while true loop as tasks. Please help.

```
from ib_insync import *
ib.connect()
while True:
    time_stamp = time.strftime("%H:%M")
    today = str(date.today())
if today == '2023-05-24' and time_stamp > '0400':
        if stocks_list.count(ticker) == 0:
            print(ticker)
            print(gain)
            print(price)
            send_price = round((price *1.10),2)
            try:        
                stock = Stock(ticker, 'SMART', 'USD')
                order = LimitOrder('BUY', 100, send_price, outsideRth = True)
                sell_trade = ib.placeOrder(stock, order)
                print(sell_trade)
                stocks_list.append(ticker)
            except Exception as e:          
                pass
                print(e)
        d = ib.portfolio()
        if d:       
            for s in d:
                print(s)
            stock = Stock(ticker, 'SMART', 'USD')
            order = LimitOrder('BUY', 50, .9600, outsideRth = True, tif = 'DAY')
            sell_trade = ib.placeOrder(stock, order)
            print(sell_trade)
```

For the while true loop to stay synced with TWS. It would work on the first order then the data being shown was not current after a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Erdewit, the fantastic creator of ib_insync, has provided [an example using asyncio.](https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/recipes.html#async-streaming-ticks)

The ib_insync is event-driven, meaning it communicates with your program by sending messages whenever certain events occur, such as a change in a position. When you call methods like ib.portfolio(), it doesn't immediately make a request to the IB server. Instead, it returns information that it has already received from these event messages.

When you're running a while True loop without giving any time for the event loop to process these messages, it could cause your program to miss some of these updates. Therefore, the state of your program may become out-of-sync with the state of the IB server.